# Please make the "Show questions" button bigger in moderator election

Tags: feature-request, design, election

I am seeing this [election page](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3?tab=nomination) on Math Overflow and the button which shows the selected nomination questions for the election is too small.

[image: excerpt of questionnaire, with "Show questions" button]

Could the "Show questions" button be increased in size?

Comment: Perhaps, it could be made bold.

Comment: Probably the "[Read more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3wwf.png)" button in each candidate's nomination could be similarly improved. At least one user in the (ongoing) [election](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3) on MathOverflow missed this button (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3#comment1108648_430812) comment and its [follow-up](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3#comment1108734_430812)).

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the font size of the "Show Questions" is 13px compared to font size of 15px in the other texts on that page.

However, I'll even go one step further, taking example from Help Center:

[image: help center view more link]

Applying the same in the election page would look like this:

[image: mockup of Show Questions with better style]

The "»" to the left of the text makes it easier to know it would expand the contents.